# Windows Server 2012 does not run batch file correctly from scheduled task

Tags: batch, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that's only 3 lines long.

What it does is simple:

```
type C:\data\file.bak >> echo "" >> file.log.bak

cscript "C:\data\Move filesA.vbs"
cscript "C:\data\Move filesB.vbs"
```

Basically all it does is take that file.bak and append it to the file.log.bak. They are just plain text files

The cscripts take the file.bak and moves it to a server location.

the `type C:\data\file.bak >> echo "" >> file.log.bak` was **just added a few hours ago**. The script runs **every 15 minutes**

When ran from a user (Double clicking the .bat file), it runs fine and copies the file to the file.log.bak with no problems

When run from the task, it doesn't execute the `type C:\data\file.bak >> echo "" >> file.log.bak` line, but executes the cscripts

My only guess would be that windows has a cached version of the batch file and it's not running the new batch file.

Is there any hint as to why it's not running the `type C:\data\file.bak >> echo "" >> file.log.bak` line when running from a scheduled task?

Comment: `type C:\data\file.bak >> echo "" >> file.log.bak` is an invalid command. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this command?

Comment: add the line to the file, but add a end line character first. It works when you run it manually (double click)

Comment: do you have better success if you break that line of code into two lines, e.g. `echo >>` and then `type...`?

Comment: Just did that, no success. I'm going to try and unschedule and schedule it again. I changed echo "" to echo. . It gives me all the same results but doesn't work from a scheduled task

Comment: does the user account configured to run the task have sufficient NTFS permissions to the files? Try running task with highest privileges.

Comment: I just had it run at the highest privilege. It just doesn't like that script for some reason. It's quite weird. Never had an issue like this before. It didn't work even with highest privilege

Comment: I found the problem and found a solution. The problem is that Windows Task Scheduler does not run the .bat file in the same directory unless you specify it. The solution is to tell the task to run in a certain directory, or (untested) to have an absolute path to the output

Comment: that's true. I just now noticed your relative reference to the file path. I always use absolute paths in scripts since this behavior is true in many cases. Glad it's fixed.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for the benefit of others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the scheduled task running in a directory.

When using relative file paths, it will not work when ran from a different directory. Microsoft has included a feature that takes the command and runs it elsewhere, not where the file is located.

Double click on the scheduled task (or hit properties), go to Actions tab, then edit the action(s). From there you will see a popup with a 'Start in (optional)' field. Put the directory that the script is in (or what directory you want it to run in)

[Popup to modify Start in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASVtr.png)